# Filtering Firestore data with timestamp from Android App

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

Objective: I need to filter the Case `Activity` entries I have with a particular date so I can display the data from that date on a `RecyclerView`. And it works fine, when I want to filter with a date range, like so.

```java
    private void filterDate(Date dateFilter1, Date dateFilter2) {
        mFilteredCaseItems.clear();
        Timestamp date1 = new Timestamp(dateFilter1);
        Timestamp date2 = new Timestamp(dateFilter2);
        EventListener<QuerySnapshot> eventListener = createList(CaseActivity.class, mFilteredCaseItems, new FirestoreDateParser.FirestoreDataCallBack() {
            @Override
            public <A extends FireStoreData> void getData(ArrayList<A> data) {
                mAdapter.setItems(data);
                if (mFilteredCaseItems.isEmpty())
                    mFilteredCaseItems.addAll((ArrayList<? extends CaseActivity>) data);
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
        db.collection("cases")
                .orderBy("timestamp").startAt(date1).endAt(date2)
                .addSnapshotListener(eventListener);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "filter by date", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

The above works perfectly. But How do I go about filtering with a single date? Not sure comparing timestamps or using `whereEqualTo()` can help since they take into account the hours and minutes and such. The efforts I made getting the date from both the filter selection date and the `Firestore` date, and locally comparing them, didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're storing timestamps in Firestore, the values are exact moments in time with nanosecond granularity. While you *can* query based on a specific timestamp, you'll have to specify the specific nanosecond that you want to get back.

If you want to select a specific date on the same data, that translates to a range of timestamps, and thus to either `startAt`/`endBefore` filters or `>=`/`<` on the timestamp field, starting, typically something like:

```
.orderBy("timestamp")
  .startAt(timestampAtMidnightOfDay)
  .endBefore(timestampAtMidnightOfNextDay)
```

If you want to be able to select all documents for a specific date with an equality filter, you'd have to add an additional field to each document with the only the date in a queryable format, typically as a string of format `"2022-06-09"` (for June 9, 2022).